# IPsec between Windows 2003 (server) and Redhat 5 (client)

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, redhat, ipsec

I need to setup data encryption within the network. Linux client machine will connect to a Windows 2003 server.

I need to enable IPsec on both the machines. Windows to Windows is working fine but Linux to Windows is failing.

- Linux is Redhat 5.0
- Windows 2003 Enterprise edition - MSSQL 2005 cluster server.

Steps to show how can we do this will be of real help.

Answer (score 0):

I once did this using [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/). Try to setup a connection using a symmetric key at the beginning. The major drawback was that this used lot of CPU-time on the Windows-Client (Linux was acting as server).

Can you give some more details - what did you use for w2w encryption and why don't you use ssh?